# Message Listener Only Receives "{isTrusted: true}" Object

Tags: javascript

This is simply what I've made. And it seems it only can recive `{isTrusted: true}` and I dont know how

```
window.addEventListener('message', (data) => {
    const json = '{"test":"huqlflgcjaptcvsptxob"}'
    document.body.innerHTML += `<p>message should be: ${JSON.stringify(json)}</p>`

    document.body.innerHTML += `<p>message recived: ${JSON.stringify(data)}</p>`
})
```

Comment: How are you checking that all the other properties are JSON-serializable? Have you tried just logging `data`?

Comment: I cant log data with console.log kinda hard to explain. And not sure what you mean by checking the JSON-serializable. This is my first time using js. This is what is getting passed in the event "{"NUICallback1":"kiflqpbiwnklxgkogjny"}"